# How can I submit a form with get method where value not added in url

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the form below, with the option fields :

```
<form action="/action_page.php" id="carform" method="get">
   <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
   <select id="cars" name="carlist" form="carform">
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
     <option value="opel">Opel</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I want that when I submit the form with the selected value `volvo` then it `does not` append in url while in case of other value selected then `get append` in url on submit.

I have tried through javascript but it did not work well.

Answer (score 4):

When usign GET HTTP method, notes that it always appends form-data into the URL in name/value pairs. To avoid this you should use the POST method, for the data sent via it is stored in the request body of the HTTP (not append in url).

For what you want, you can simply add a javascript function, that switch your form method to GET or POST, according to the value of option in select tag. ie POST when Volvo and GET else.

Here is the code :

```
<form action="action_page.php" id="carform" method="">
    <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
    <select id="cars" name="carlist" form="carform" onchange="switchPostGet()">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send data"/>
</form>
<script>
    function switchPostGet() {
        var carName = document.getElementById("cars").value;
        if (carName == "volvo") {
            document.getElementById("carform").method = "post";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("carform").method = "get";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: correct @mwabo, we need to be in POST type, to submit a form data without getting appended to URL.

Comment: Any other method. please let me know because i dont want to change form method

Comment: Is there any purpose why you don't want to change the form method? By the way I found this article on HTTP Request methods intersting https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Answer (score 0):

If we are not willing to change the form method, and we just want to make 1 value disappear before submission, perhaps using JavaScript to invalidate the input before sending it if it is not set? (and either disable it or remove it depending on the value)

```
<form action="/action_page.php" id="carform" method="get" onsubmit="preparateForm()">
   <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
   <select id="cars" name="carlist" form="carform">
       <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
       <option value="saab">Saab</option>
       <option value="opel">Opel</option>
       <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
</form>

<script>

function preparateForm(){
    let input = document.getElementById("cars");
    if (input.value == "volvo") {
        input.disabled = true; //a disabled input will not be appended
        input.remove(); //even remove it!
    }
    return true; //continue with submission
}
</script>
```